# How can I call Secret in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, huggingface

I'm using Dockerfile in Huggingface, but I can't invoke a link to the private repository, it's stored in Secret, under the name TOKEN, here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git


WORKDIR /app


ENV REPO_URL=${TOKEN}
RUN git clone $REPO_URL


COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /app/requirements.txt


COPY . .


CMD ["python", "application.py"]
```

I've tried different options but can't find the information I'm looking for